Is it appropriate to ask for help understanding definitions and basic concepts? Or do questions for the most part have to be more interesting?
I'm new here. Let's say I can't understand a concept like how to add fractions or maybe I can't visualize what a gradient of function is or I can't take a determinant or I can't make out what Lie Group means.
Is it appropriate to ask about these types of things?
Like I could show my work and ask a question about it or say what I think the terms mean in my own words or describe what I think a gradient looks like.
Or would we say there's enough resources out there already.
What makes a good or interesting questions? Does it have to have a new wrinkle to make it more provocative?

You are new?

@MartinBrandenburg FYI, the OP is new to the Mathematics Meta site, but is not new to the main Mathematics site, as your link indicates.

As long as the question is stated clearly, includes context (like background, source and motivation of the question) and your attempts, viz., is of good quality, there is no restriction on the level of the topics of questions you can ask on Math SE.
As quoted in the tour page,

Mathematics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields.

But, you should ensure that your question has not been asked before(in which case it will be closed a duplicate). This is because publishing a duplicate question only increases the number of places where ideas/solutions for solving it are posted, but it is beneficial for the community as a whole to have all answers at one place. It also wastes the time and the effort of those who have stumbled upon the duplicate question and don’t know it’s a duplicate and are willing to answer it, since it will be closed sooner or later.
This can be ensured in $3$ ways:
$1.$ By typing the relevant key words in the search bar of the MSE website.
$2.$ By googling the relevant key words and formulae and typing ‘stack exchange’ at the end(I personally use this a lot for SE sites other than Math SE.)
$3.$ By searching the primary equations involved in the Approach0 search engine

Also add that the question should not have been asked before.  The kind of question the OP refers to may well have been asked here several times (fraction addition, gradient of function, introduction to Lie groups etc.)

Note that the final character of Approach0 is a zero, not an oh.

@JohnBentin I've typed 0, not o.

Yes, exactly as I did. It's just that it looks very similar to an oh in the (non-TeX) typeface used by MSE.

Elaborating point 2: searching “ site:math.stackexchange.com” will only yield results from MSE which are related to .
